# Single header for multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, seo, web-crawler

I want to use one header for all pages in my project directory for website. But I am little bit confused. If I kept single header and import it in all web pages then will it affect SEO? can crawler crawl those header for each page? I want the way which does not affect SEO of my website.

Comment: if you're dynamically replacing the content of the description and title per page you should be good to go

Comment: Please share the code what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

in **header.php** use static content such as css,javascript etc.

**header.php**

```
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,800,800italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

I think, your problem is solved by doing this

Answer (score 1):

Using a single header for your entire website will not hurt the SEO of your website - upwards of 90% of websites do it.

Comment: but how to do that? I mean using single header for all pages. I need a proper way

Comment: Yes its right as mentioned by @Brendan. It will not affect SEO at all. I myself have used it in almost every site I have developed so far.

Comment: Make a template file and use it by including it every were.

Comment: Please share your code what you have done so far. So that suggestion can be made in right direction.

Comment: @Vickrant How to include?

Comment: @GauravDeshpande a fundamental element of PHP development: [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)